# Sound stopped working after upgrading to Linux 5.4 (Intel HD Audio)

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux, sound-card, pulse-audio

After upgrading from Linux 5.3 to Linux v5.4.2 on Arch Linux, all of my audio stopped working. The only thing I see in Gnome 3’s Sound settings is “Dummy Output” and `aplay --list-pcm` says: “No card(s) found.” and running `alsactl init` says: “alsactl: init:1759: No soundcards found.”

I’ve tried many solutions already.

Comment: spelling : you meant 'alsactl' instead of 'aslactl'

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is how I was able to resolve this:

1. `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`
2. Find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` to the end of it. (ex: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"`)
3. `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
4. Reboot the system.

Comment: Any explanation about that option?

Comment: HOW DO I UPVOTE THIS A BILLION TIMES? NOTHING OUT THERE WORKED AND I HAVE BEEN TO GOOGLE'S SECOND PAGE. THIS DID. THAT HOPE IN YOUR NAME MEANS SOMETHING SIR

Comment: this comment tho ^

Comment: After adding this option, do you still have microphone working?

Comment: I had to scour the internet for over 3 days before i found all this and painstakingly pieced it all together. It was excruciating!!

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote my question, too, as i did this just to save you guys my utter frustration.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I have no explanation. This is an arcane magick incarnation I pieced together from scouring the entire Internet, including kernel emails :-/

Comment: Works for me, but some people report they put the option in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` instead, which seems less invasive than changing the grub configuration?

Comment: This saved my butt again on 20 October 2020.

Comment: I don't know why but this didn't work for me.  The problem popped up after Jun 15 2022 update.  as mentioned above I had to change alsa-base.conf as in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169798/i-still-get-dummy-output-for-audio-after-installing-alsa-base-and-pulseaudio.

Answer (score 9):

The option `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` is deprecated on newer kernels, you may use `snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` instead.
But be aware, it's slightly different meaning.

Comment: Still no mic after this, only speakers. Any clue?

Comment: This literally didn’t work for me. Doing `echo snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 > /etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf`. The sound cards are completely undetected still.

Comment: IIRC, the file I found this is:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ed8780e3f2ecc82645342d070c6b4e530532e680/sound/pci/hda/hda_intel.c#L166
When I tested it with some hardware no longer in my possession, I added it as a boot parameter modifying the grub config as described in the accepted answer and did not modify the alsa.conf

Comment: @hopeseekr Try `echo "options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to persist the kernel parameters (for example on Pop_OS!), you'll have to use kernelstub to append the parameter.

Either use `sudo kernelstub -a intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` or `sudo kernelstub -a snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` (depending on kernel version). Then you can check if it was appended with running the command `sudo cat /boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop_Os-current.conf`.

If you append the parameter directly it will get overwritten after rebooting.

Comment: What needs to be run after this command for PopOS? I tried running that but I don't know what it's doing or what I should expect.

Comment: @davidparks21 I added a command to check if it was appended (see above).
You can delete it again with the command `sudo kernelstub -d intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` or `sudo kernelstub -d snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0`

Answer (score 1):

Above solution by hopeseekr seems to be working for Dell G3 3590 with Nvidia GTX 1650 for newest ubuntu 20.04 installation in Dual Boot mode along with Windows 10. Initially there was no sound and no system brightness controller. I have tried following possible solutions by updating the grub but nothing seems to work :

1. Updating `/etc/default/grub` with `quiet splash` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.
2. Updating `/etc/default/grub` with `nouveau.nomodeset=0` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`.

Checking `alsamixer` in the the terminal was also not showing Intel sound card. Only Nvidia sound card was detected.
This has completely solved the problem. I have been searching for this solution since months. It detects the intel sound card correctly in Ubuntu 18.04 installation but was failing to do so in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

In Recent (i.e., post 2020) Fedora or RHEL derivatives, as superuser do:

- vim /etc/default/grub
- Find GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX and add *snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1* as another option inside the "quotes"
- grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
- Reboot the system.

This recipe assumes that you only lack being able to detect your physical device, therefore, the ALSA, lame, VLC, etc., drivers and/or plugins, plus other multimedia stuff, has already been installed by following other tutorials (if necessary) and your user is part of the *audio* group. A device name should appear if you type `lspci -v | grep -A 7 -i Audio`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by the config option `SND_HDA_INTEL_DETECT_DMIC` being enabled in the 5.4 kernel (https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64720).

The suggested fix is to undo the change by passing `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` as a kernel parameter, as explained in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1509313/1121110).

Comment: `SND_HDA_INTEL_DETECT_DMIC` was removed in favour of `SND_INTEL_DSP_CONFIG`. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=82d9d54a6c0ee8b12211fa4e59fd940a2da4e063

Answer (score 0):

Current solution may be that:
`add snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=0` in kernel parameters (`/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` to end of line `linux` or other places depend of your bootloader)

Comment: No, you shouldn't edit the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, on Debian unstable with this sound card:

```
lspci -nn | grep -i audio         
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
```

was

```
echo "options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf
```

With this option, it uses the legacy snd_hda_intel instead of SOF.

Comment: However, the older message on the kernel says: `DMICs cannot be handled by the HDaudio legacy driver and are currently only supported by the SOF driver.` So this has fixed sound for me, but no mic. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=82d9d54a6c0ee8b12211fa4e59fd940a2da4e063

Answer (score 0):

After running these 3 commands in a terminal I got sound working on HP Pavilion gaming laptop

`echo "options snd_hda_intel dmic_detect=0" > audiofix.conf`

`sudo mv audiofix.conf /etc/modprobe.d/`

`reboot`

Comment: Please improve your answer with an explanation so that the readers can see its the right answer without referring to references.